# SQL server 2014 fails on start attempt, Error 17054

Tags: sql-server

The error I'm running into first occurred when I tried to connect to my SQl server database in Toad for SQl Server. The error message stated **The System cannot find the file specified**.

I opened SQL Server configuration manager and the SQL Server was stopped. I tried to start it but it failed. Here is the error in the log:

> 2016-07-07 08:52:09.01 Server      SQL Server is terminating because of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user action is required
>
> 2016-07-07 08:52:10.25 spid20s     Service Broker manager has shut down.
>
> 2016-07-07 08:52:10.25 spid20s     Error: 17054, Severity: 16, State: 1.

Comment: What you pasted in question is not total log of why you are not able to start SQL Server.please check error logs and eventvwr as well

Answer (score 0):

Check the service account. 
It might be invalid, wrong password or lack right to logon as a service.
Try login as localsystem just to eliminate this possibility.
Also check the SPNs.

Answer (score 0):

> Check if the SQL Browser service is running. If yes then stop it and
>   disable (if you are using only one default instance.)
>
> I had the same issue and after stopping/disabling the SQL Browser
>   service; it worked for me.

The SQL Server Browser Service is installed often in Disabled state (It is preferred to be disabled unless required). 
It is only required for named instances or instances listening on non-default ports.

Your application installer should only restart the Browser service if needed, and certainly should check for a disabled service and ask an administrator permission to enable the service .